# How to access local file when building from Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need `hello.rpm` when I build from Dockerfile, but this rpm file is not available online.

Right now I'm serving the file by firing up a temporary web server, but ideally I'd like to run a *build* command which makes this local file available inside the container.

Is this possible?

---

My build command:

```
docker build -t fredrik/helloworld:1.0 .
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:6
RUN rpm -ivh hello.rpm
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Why don't you [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) the file inside the container before executing `RUN`?

```
FROM centos:6
COPY hello.rpm /tmp/hello.rpm
RUN rpm -ivh /tmp/hello.rpm
```

This assumes that `hello.rpm` is next to your `Dockerfile` when you build it.

Comment: This means you end up with two copies of the file in the resulting Docker image - both the RPM and the installed binaries.  If the files are large and your connection is slow, it's not fantastic.

Comment: If size is an issue, after doing the "RUN rpm -ivh /tmp/hello.rpm" just do a "RUN rm /tmp/hello.rpm" to delete the RPM from the image.

Comment: @Luciano this will not reduce the image size, since AFAIK even if the file is not visible anymore after the RUN rm directive, it's still present in the layer created by the COPY one. Image inspection tools will show it.

Answer (score 2):

Otherwise if an internet connection is not a limiting factor while you're working just:

1. Upload the file a cloud as Dropbox
2. Go to your docker shell and `wget https://www.cloudnameXYZ.com/filename`